# Mass Import problem for images

Tags: database, import, image, products-management

I'm using magmi to import more than 30.000 products with images.

The problem is with images that they are imported but all of them are excluded.

Is there any sql query that I can use and get all images included?

I used this query but only one row effected

```
update `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` set disabled=1 where `value_id` in (select `value_id` from `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` where value in (select value from `catalog_product_entity_varchar` where `attribute_id`=(select `attribute_id` from `eav_attribute` where attribute_code='image' and `entity_type_id`=4)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to set all images as include, simply use below sql query,

```
update `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` set disabled=0 where disabled=1
```